# How to backup data of first computer to the hard drive of second?

Tags: networking, permissions, hard-drive, backup

I have two computers connected to same network. First computer (laptop) is for my  primary use. I use Ubuntu's `Backups` program to backup my data for that I have to connect external hard drive. Now I am tired of connecting and removing the external hard drive.
So I keep it connected to a second computer (desktop) but want to backup the data directly to external hard drive connected to second computer.

What things I need to do?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Backups program. Does it allow you to type in a path where you want to save your backup, or do you have to select an actual external harddrive? If you can type in a path where you want to save your backup, you'll need to share the external harddrive over the network, for instance as a SAMBA share. Do both computers run Ubuntu?

Comment: @Tobias both of them run ubuntu and yes I can set any path in backup program

Comment: Depending on which version of Ubuntu, it could be as simple as right clicking on the folder on the desktop and selecting 'Local Network Share' and adding a line to /etc/fstab on the laptop. Here are two examples: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/02/share-a-folder-in-ubuntu-14-04/ https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Comment: @Tobias thanks man, your suggestion works. I have found a simple answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have later found that there is an option to backup to Samba/Network location in `Deja dup backups` itself. *silly me, couldn’t find before I posted the question ;-)*

All you have to do is first launch the `Backups` program from dash. Now open `Storage location` tab.
in `Storage location` drop down menu select `Windows share` and input other details as follows:

1. Server: it will be the static IP address of the computer whose folder you want to keep the backup in.
2. Folder: name of the folder on second computer (give absolute path) you are keeping backup. Also specify subdirectory if any
3. Username: In my case the samba shared folder is password protected, for that I have to enter the username by which I login when I mount it or open it while browsing the network. You will be asked password too, in a separate dialog window. For automatic backup you might wanna check `remember password`
4. Domain Name: Its usually `WORKGROUP`

[image: Deja dup backup to samba shared network location]

Answer (score 2):

You may use nfs to mount your directory from second computer.

**Setup nfs server on second computer:**

1. `apt-get install nfs-server` and start nfs server.
2. Let say you have mounted the External HDD on the `/mnt/backup`, so we will export this as NFS share.
3. Edit `/etc/exports`:

   ```
   /mnt/backup  *(rw,no_root_squash,async)
   ```
4. Export the share:

   ```
   exporfs -a
   ```
5. To verify:

   ```
   exportfs
   ```

**On the first computer:**

1. nfs-common should be default package, if not, install `apt-get install nfs-common`.
2. Mount the NFS share:

   ```
   mount first:/mnt/backup /mnt/backup
   ```

**Deja Dup:**
Now you will able to backup using Deja Dup via `Folders` option.

Comment: as mentioned in answer I am using `Backups` program, also know as `Deja dup`

Comment: edited my answer to suite your needs